# alignment in gtk+

Tags: user-interface, gtk

I want my heading on top and the next button on right bottom. But I am not able to do this. It is displaying next in middle right and heading little above bottom. And with next button I want to move to other window, here I am calling `gtk_main_quit()`. My code is:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

        GtkWidget *window;
        GtkWidget *next;

        GtkWidget *align;
        GtkWidget *label;
        GtkWidget *vbox;
        GtkWidget *hbox;
        GtkWidget *halign;
        GtkWidget *valign;


        gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Center");//title position
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),600,500);//size
        gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);//position
        vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 5);

        valign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 1, 0, 0);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), valign);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

        hbox = gtk_hbox_new(FALSE, 3);

        next = gtk_button_new_with_label("Next");
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(next, 70, 30);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hbox), next);
        halign = gtk_alignment_new(1, 0, 0, 0);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(halign), hbox);
        align = gtk_alignment_new(0, 0, 1, 0);

        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), halign, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(next), "clicked",
                        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));
        label = gtk_label_new("No. of projects are:\n");

        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), label);

        gtk_widget_show_all(window);

        g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


        gtk_main ();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add elements to `vbox` from top to bottom, so if you want the label to appear on top, you should move the lines:

```
    label = gtk_label_new("No. of projects are:\n");  
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), label);
```

so that label is the *first object* that is added to `vbox`, right after where you initialize it.
Then the "next" button will also move to the bottom right corner.

There is a chapter in the GTK+ 2.0 Tutorial about this: [Packing Widgets](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/c354.html).